# If the coefficient of determination is a measure based on variance, then what about standard deviation instead?

Tags: correlation, variance, standard-deviation, r-squared

Background: I've been teaching a very simple course of introductory Statistics for a few years now and we cover linear correlation and the Correlation Coefficient ($r$). I want to introduce the Correlation of Determination ($r^2$) but I need to get my head around it first.

1. If we measure $r^2=0.8$ it is OK to made a broad statement like: "There is an 80% correlation between these variables."?
2. The unexplained variation: $1-r^2=\frac{Var(y-\hat{y})}{Var(y)}$ is a ratio of variances. So why use Variance and not Standard Deviation here? Variance is a somewhat abstract measure since its value has no specific meaning, whereas Standard Deviation is a more concrete measure of how a given variable varies.

Since $Var(x)=s_x^2$ then $\frac{s_{y-\hat{y}}}{s_y}=\sqrt{1-r^2}$
should be the unexplained Standard Deviation. However the value of $\sqrt{1-r^2}$ will always be a bigger value than $1-r^2$.

For example: if $r=0.9$ then $r^2=0.81$ and so there is an 19% unexplained variance. However $\sqrt{0.19}\approx0.436$ meaning there is a whopping 43.6% unexplained Standard Deviation (or there is only 56.4% explained by the model) which seems quite bad given the original correlation was quite good.

So, I guess this explains why we don't use Standard Deviation in place of Variance, but then that just leads to the question of why doesn't a ratio of Standard Deviation work well here? It seems a reasonable thing to calculate, but clearly it doesn't give a reasonable measure of correlation.

Comment: Variances have some [special properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) not shared by standard deviations (e.g. variances of sums have a simple form, even simpler with independence); this is part of why variances get used a lot.

Comment: [Of course, you could arguably claim the present $R^2$ formula is "based on standard deviations" since it's effectively a ratio of squared standard deviations.]

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, but my first thought was that the squaring was artificially inflating the size of the correlation, which is why I wanted to explore SD instead.

Comment: How are you defining "correlation" there?

Comment: @Glen_b I just mean "correlation" as a measure of how well the data fits a linear model. There are already $r$ and $r^2$ which measure correlation but are quite different. E.G. $r=0.6$ seems good until you realise $r^2=0.36$. Or perhaps $r^2=0.9$ seems really good, but not as good as $1-\sqrt{1-r^2}=0.68$ (using SD instead of Var).